# Qmake creating Visual Studio project - set "Working Directory"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qmake

How do I set the the Visual Studio "Working Directory" field in a .pro file to be read with qmake?

It would be great to avoid having to set this each time I run qmake.

I have looked [here](http://pepper.troll.no/s60prereleases/doc/qmake-variable-reference.html) but am not sure if any of them work...

---

[image]

Comment: +1 for showing me this option :).

Answer (score 0):

Not as far I can tell - I don't think there is even an way option to change that in automated way with vcproj.

Someone [reported](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-407?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3aactivity-stream-issue-tab) this as bug/feature request, but it seems that there were no progress made since then.